# Setting up the webdriver/selenium server for protractor

Tags: windows, selenium-webdriver, protractor

So we use protractor for `e2e` testing. the CI system is `jenkins`. And don't want to use jenkins to be the selenium server too. Hence, i have set-up a separate another node, to be just the selenium server. The protractor conf file have the selenium address pointed to this node say

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://remote-node.com:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['Scripts\\test\\**\\*spec.js'],
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 12000,
        onComplete: null,
        isVerbose: true,
        showColors: true,
        includeStackTrace: true
    },
```

And then on the remote-node, i have to start up the selenium server manually by loggin and executing the `batch` file. If I create a batch file and make it to start at the boot time, using the windows taskscheduler. The batch is executed and i can see the process running in the background.

This is the batch.

```
call "C:\Program Files\nodejs\nodevars.bat"
call webdriver-manager start --standalone
```

But protractor doesn't seem to like browsers that are running at the background.

How is this issue being handled? i.e. using a remote selenium server that starts up at boot time in windows? And the whole idea of using a in-house remote selenium server for protractor. My test with the task scheduler have not been successful.

Answer (score -1):

"**But protractor doesn't seem to like browsers that are running at the background**." 
Protractor always initiates new instance of the browser, what exactly you are running in the background?

Once you trigger your Jenkins job, selenium server is started and if you trigger the same job again, I am not sure about the situation of the selenium server.

Which browser are you using? if you are using Chrome and Firefox you can use 
"directConnect: true" in your config file, you don't have to start selenium server manually.

Comment: Please let me know why this is down voted. I would like to improve my self.
I told the possible ways and what exactly it does.